# Duplicated code sections - move to a service?

Tags: service, architecture, soa, code-duplication

I have a `C#` application that enables users to write a test and execute it (`client`). It also supports distributed execution over multiple machines using a central `server` and `agents` on said machines.
The `agent` is practically a duplication of the original execution ability but it is in a standalone solution.
We'd like to refactor that because:

1. Code duplication.
2. If a user will try to write and execute on a machine that runs an `agent`, there will be a problematic collision.

I'm considering 2 options:

1. Move this execution to a service, that both `client` and `agent` will use. I mean a service that will run locally, not a web service.
2. Merge `client` and `agent` - we'll have no `agent`, but the `server` will communicate with the `client` as an `agent` instead.

I have no experience in working with services. Are there any known advantages/disadvantages to either options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common library shared by both client and agent sounds more appropriate to allow simple cases such as just using the client and avoid the overhead of having to set up an extra service locally.